# How to set default date to today in google form?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to set in a google form response the today date (Not hardcoded) when submited

I'm accesing the form, adding a date question, setting the title and the help text, but nothing more

```
function myFunction() {
    var myForm = FormApp.openById("MyFormID");
    var formDate = myForm.addDateItem();
    formDate.setTitle('Ciclo');
    formDate.setHelpText('Ciclo de registro');
    //This is doing nothing at all
    //var formDateResponse = formDate.createResponse(new Date());
 }
```

Im only getting the date question unfilled

Comment: By default the timestamp will be added with your response in google sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#) has a [getTimestamp()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getTimestamp()) function built into it.

If you are using an [onSubmit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4) you can get it by:

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var response = e.response;
  var timestamp = response.getTimestamp(); //Date Object!
}
```

*It's important to note* that if you have an onSubmit Trigger in Google Sheets it does not provide the `e.response` FormResponse object, but instead a values array, namedValues array, or range object.

Comment: thanks a lot. Finally i wll not use the date as intended, and i will register the timestamp automatically generated in the csv export.